# Why my print statement inside the swap function is giving such output?

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference, swap

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
    printf("The value of x and y inside the function is x = %d and y = %d", x, y);
}
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y =3;
    swap(&x, &y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
The value of x and y inside the function is x = 6422300 and y = 6422296

Why the value of x is 6422300 and y is 6422296 inside the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int* x, int* y){
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
    printf("The value of x and y inside the function is x = %d and y = %d", x, y);
}
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y =3;
    swap(&x,&y);
    printf("\nThe value of x and y in the main is x = %d and y = %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
The value of x and y inside the function is x = 6422300 and y = 6422296
The value of x and y in the main is x = 3 and y = 2

I tried to write the print statement for x and y in main separately, then it worked properly. But why it wasn't working inside function?

Comment: This close makes a good argument for always compiling with warnings enabled (and heeding them)

Answer (score 4):

Your code invoked undefined behaviour as you pass the pointer not the integer to the `printf`. `%d` is expecting `int`. You need to dereference `x` and `y`

```
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
    printf("The value of x and y inside the function is x = %d and y = %d\n", *x, *y);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to print a newline at the end of debugging output. It makes it more likely to appear at a good time and reduces the risk that other output will be added to the end of the debugging output, thereby confusing you.  If the next output were a number, it would appear attached to the value of `y`, leading to a fraught debugging session.